# How to set system images (path?) when creating an Android AVD?

Tags: android, cordova, sdk

I'm trying to create an AVD with Android on Linux. When I run `android create avd` in my Cordova project folder, I get this message:

```
  -k --package : Package path of the system image for this AVD (e.g.
                 'system-images;android-19;google_apis;x86'). [required]
```

My problem is that I have no idea what to add for this option and can't find any good references online. Apparently I have system images installed:

[image]

But how do I reference these? I took a stab at it based on the example and I get this error:

```
david@david-Virtual-Machine:~/projects/test-test$ android create avd --package "system-images;android-25;google-apis;x86" --name "foo"
*************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
*************************************************************************
Running //home/david/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd --package system-images;android-25;google-apis;x86 --name foo

Error: Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are:
```

(In my platforms folder the only platform listed is android-25)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Pay attention that `android` is **deprecated**. Use `avdmanager`.

First, you need to download the necessary packages.
Example of downloading API 23 packages for x86 emulators:

```
 ./sdkmanager "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86"
```

Then accept the license agreement

```
 ./sdkmanager --licenses
```

and then create your emulator

```
./avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86" -b x86 -c 100M -d 7 -f
```

Comment: Run the above commands  from `<yourinstallationpath>/Android/Sdk/tools/bin`

Comment: @jabu.hlong Not necessary if you set the correct *PATH* in the environment variables (at least on Windows). And if one works a lot with CLI tools like a normal person, one should definitely add that to the path list.

Comment: In my case I had an issue, because I used single quotes instead of double quotes on Windows.

Answer (score 18):

The message

> Error: Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are:

indicates that the package could not be found - I bet the platform wasn't correctly installed .. In order to fix that problem, You can try installing it using the following commands:

```
android update sdk -u --filter platform-tools,android-25
sdkmanager --verbose "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86"
```

and then create the avd using: `avdmanager -v create avd -n x86 -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86" -g "google_apis"`.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 14):

You can also list your installed and available packages using:

```
$ sdkmanager --list
```

To install a system image use this:

```
$ sdkmanager  "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86_64"
```

Then as stated above create the avd:

```
$ ./avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86_64" -b x86 -c 100M -d 7 -f
```

Comment: One up for installing the system image first! That has brought me one step closer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put package path with semicolons.

an example of a valid path would be

avdmanager create avd -k "system-images;android-16;google_apis;x86"

and put all other options that you require.

Answer (score 0):

As the advice properly says, the `android` command is deprecated. You need to use `avdmanager` and also specify the exact string that appears on your available packages as the package argument. In your case:

`avdmanager create avd --package "android-25" --name "foo"`

Answer (score 0):

Considering the SDK is installed under `/Users/<your_user>/Library/Android/sdk` folder which is the Android Studio preferred SDK location, but it works fine under `/usr/local/share/android-sdk` as well, which is a location pretty much used on CI mostly.

### Prerequisites:

See for brew, python3 and NodeJS on nvm see gist https://gist.github.com/agrcrobles/3d945b165871c355b6f169c317958e3e

### Java 14

> Open JDK 14 works fine with gradle 6.x

Preferred: To install the JDKs 8 ( LTS )
AdoptOpenJDK:

```
# brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk via cask

brew install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8
```

#### SDK preferred location

sdk can be installed on /Library/Android/sdk or /usr/local/ to be sure check it by

```
which sdkmanager
```

#### Export ANDROID_HOME

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
```

or

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/share/android-sdk"
```

Install all of the Android SDK components (you will be prompted to agree to license info and then this will take a while to run):

If you need to have openjdk first in your PATH run:

echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

```
## android-29
touch ~/.android/repositories.cfg
yes | sdkmanager --licenses
sdkmanager --update
sdkmanager --no_https --install emulator
sdkmanager --no_https --install platform-tools
sdkmanager --no_https --install 'system-images;android-29;google_apis_playstore;x86_64'
sdkmanager --no_https --install 'extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager'
sdkmanager --no_https --install 'build-tools;29.0.2'
sdkmanager --no_https --install 'platforms;android-29'
sdkmanager --list

avdmanager list (find device skin id, lets use pixel 17)
avdmanager create avd -f -n test -d 17 -k 'system-images;android-29;google_apis_playstore;x86_64'
avdmanager list avd (or emulator -list-avds)
```

Happy code!!